# How to get alt text from images in a docx file using Open XML and C#

Tags: asp.net, image, openxml

I am creating a web form that will do a 508 compliance check on word documents. I am looking through MSDN and other sites for getting the information I need from a file the user selects. The one thing I can't find is how to find images, and check to see if they have alternative text. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images inserted into 2007+ Word documents are `Drawing` objects. So you can traverse the XML for `w:drawing` members.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.drawing.aspx

The `w:drawing` member will have a child called `w:inline` which is a part of the `Inline` class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.wordprocessing.inline.aspx

The `w:inline` member will have a member called `wd:docPr`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.wordprocessing.docproperties.aspx

The `wd:docPr` member may have a field called `title` which houses the alternative text title and a field called `descr` which houses all the alternative text.

Example XML:

```
<w:drawing xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="357A850A" wp14:editId="384E9053" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
        <wp:extent cx="5943600" cy="4457700" />
        <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0" />
        <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="ALL TEXT HERE" title="ALT TEXT TITLE HERE"/>
        ...
```

I highly recommend you use the OpenXML Productivity Tool that comes with the OpenXML SDK.

Comment: I thought alt text was in descr in dorPr?

Comment: You are right. I was confusing web images alt text (where they have only one field). Updated answer. I can only provide C# code if you need an example, I can't do ASP.

Comment: Awesome ty ty. So I need to pick up LINQ basics from what I understand, at least to do this a little easier. This is new coding for me, I am a Java and c or C++ guy. How would you cycle through the drawing elements, then grab the ones where inline doesnt have a docPr with descr attribute?

Comment: Here is some sample C# code, best I can do (this is from memory, but will compile and should work): http://pastebin.com/dEWPTGag

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. I greatly appreciate the help. I have been grinding through a LINQ book and the MSDN getting ready for this project. Big thanks for giving me a starting push.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing slightly more easily with unzip and a copy of lxprintf (part of the LTXML2 toolkit), by unzipping the slides in a loop and running lxprintf on each one to locate the wp:docPr element and output the values of @descr and @title, eg

```
for f in `unzip -l demo.pptx | grep ppt/slides/slide.*\.xml | awk '{print $NF}'`; do 
  unzip -p demo.pptx $f |\
    lxprintf -e 'w:drawing/wp:inline/wp:docPr' "%s, %s\n" @descr @title -
done
```